# Cassandra IllegalArgumentException creating keyspace

Tags: java, cassandra

I am using Cassandra 1.2, on Mac OS X Lion.

I have dropped into ./bin/cassandra-cli and am attempting to create a keyspace using the following syntax:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE my_keyspace WITH REPLICATION = { 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 };
```

This command is copied almost entirely from the documentation for Cassandra 1.2 [here](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/cql_cli/cql/CREATE_KEYSPACE), but I am getting a Java error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient$AddKeyspaceArgument.REPLICATION
```

Does anyone know the root cause of this error and how I could go about fixing it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using **cassandra-cli** this is the correct syntax:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE my_keyspace
with placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy'
and strategy_options = {replication_factor:1};
```

(syntax you tried with is for **cqlsh**)

Comment: I am reading Cassandra: The definitive Guide, it API version is 10.0.0 and the syntax used there is 

 [default@unknown] create keyspace MyKeyspace with replication_factor=1
ab67bad0-ae2c-11df-b642-e700f669bcfc
However it did not work for but you answer did !

Answer (score 1):

That's the `create keyspace` command for CQL3 with `bin/cqlsh -3`
Schildmeijer's answer is for CLI